# PayPal express checkout billing addresses in sandbox

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, express-checkout

I have tried enabling receiving billing addresses with PayPal sandbox by adding the following option:

REQBILLINGADDRESS=1 (documented here: https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pfp_expresscheckout_pp.pdf)

For the call to SetExpressCheckout.

However, I receive the following error:

```
'ACK': 'Failure',
'BUILD': '6675672',
'CORRELATIONID': '4d9afd327754a',
'L_ERRORCODE0': '11601',
'L_LONGMESSAGE0': 'Billing address request is not enabled for merchant',
'L_SEVERITYCODE0': 'Error',
'L_SHORTMESSAGE0': 'Request for billing address failed',
'TIMESTAMP': '2013-06-28T16:32:22Z',
'VERSION': '72.0'
```

I know receiving billing addresses is possible as the Humble Bundle do it here:

[image: Humble bundle paypal]

How do I change my sandbox account to enable billing address requests? and what do I need to do in order to enable this for a live account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Along with passing over the variable in your code, you also need to have the feature enabled on your account.  For your live account you will need to contact PayPal Bussiness/Customer support and request this to be enabled on your account.  I have enabled it on your sandbox account, you should now be able to test with it.

Comment: For anyone else with the same problem can you please post the link to "PayPal Bussiness/Customer support" because you have quite a few support systems and the ones I tried I got no response from.

Comment: You can reach Business/Customer Support at 1-888-221-1161 of by visiting https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/helpcenter/helphub/home/

Comment: is there any way to make this work with the Button Manager API?

Comment: All our clients have given up on PayPal express because of this, not one person has been able to correctly enable this on our account despite talking on multiple occassions to support in Australia, India and Ireland

Comment: This was answered a couple of years ago... Is the answer still valid?  It doesn't sound very user-friendly for a customer to have to call to make a change like this to their account.

Comment: I called PayPal Business Support on Feb 15, 2017. They told me they do not supply billing information. It is my assessment that it is no longer possible to retrieve billing information.

Comment: @PP_MTS_Chad Could you also enable this for my staging account. Merchant ID = B2MHLJJGL6DX8